# TPanel does not AutoSize when containing a TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, twebbrowser

I've found a [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449362/xe6-tlistview-column-widths-become-zero-if-you-read-column-width) regression between Delphi 5 and Delphi XE6.

I have a `TPanel` that is set to `AutoSize` itself to its contents (Panel is green):

[image]

When the `TPanel` contains any other control, e.g. a `TListView`, the panel will auto-size itself to the size of the contained listview:

[image]

But when the contained control is a `TWebBrowser` (or the replacement [`TEmbeddedWB`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/embeddedwb/)), the panel will not auto-size:

[image]

### Must be TWebBrowser's fault

There must be some VCL plumbing needed for auto-sizing that the `TWebBrowser` VCL wrapper gets wrong. What i need to know what was broken in XE6 and the fix for it.

[User user1611655 had a good workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20224876/12597):

> I had a similar problem.
>
> It was solved by putting a `TPanel` "underneath" the `TWebBrowser`, and aligning the web browser to `alClient`.

I'm less interested in a workaround, as a **fix** - I can add it to our other pile of VCL source fixes. In reality, since i use the much improved `TEmbeddedWB` control, the fix can be put in there; leaving `TWebBrowser` broken.

## Steps to Reproduce

The **Form1.pas**:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
     Panel1: TPanel;
     WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
  private
     { Private declarations }
  public
     { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

The **Form1.dfm**:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 248
  ClientWidth = 373
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 32
    Top = 32
     Width = 209
     Height = 97
     AutoSize = True
     BevelOuter = bvNone
     Color = clLime
     ParentBackground = False
     TabOrder = 0
     object WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser
        Left = 0
        Top = 0
        Width = 190
        Height = 161
        ParentShowHint = False
        ShowHint = False
        TabOrder = 0
        ControlData = {
          4C00000023260000E40500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
          000000004C000000000000000000000001000000E0D057007335CF11AE690800
          2B2E126208000000000000004C0000000114020000000000C000000000000046
          8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
          00000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000}
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Must be along the same lines of how when you draw a box while dropping a web browser, no matter what size you make the box, it still scales itself how it wants.

Comment: It has something to do with the way the panel calculates the size for the web browser control. If you drop the TWebBrowser on the panel and then use the keyboard to increase it's dimensions, and then toggle the panel's AutoSize property off and back on in the Object Inspector, the panel will resize itself to the proper size.

Comment: I think it must be driven by the creation of a `TWebBrowser`. Specifically, overriding the defaults and resetting itself. Doesn't seem to happen once it's been there, except I have seen strange behavior still. I think the control loads itself twice, and the second time disregards whatever you may have instructed it the first time (for example, position/size properties). I wouldn't be surprised if I were to find something like `Application.ProcessMessages;` somewhere in there... :-)

Comment: Then again, it could just be simple failure to forward Windows messages...

Comment: Usually I will set `WebBrowser1.Align := alClient`. And I update the size of `Panel1` instead.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 [Panels inside an autosize panel do not work either](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394970/tpanel-does-not-autosize-when-containing-a-tpanel?noredirect=1#comment46969639_29394970)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is caused by two regressions.

- One in in **TWinControl.AlignControls**
- The other was caused by a change put into **TOleControl.SetBounds**, although the actual bug is in **TWinControl.WMWindowPosChanged**.

### The "Nothing autosizes ever" bug

The first bug i detailed in the Stackoverflow question [TPanel does not AutoSize when containing a TPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29421315/12597):

```
procedure TWinControl.AlignControls(AControl: TControl; var Rect: TRect);
begin
   //...snip

   // Apply any constraints
   if Showing and ((sfWidth in FScalingFlags) or (sfHeight in FScalingFlags)) then
      DoAdjustSize;

   //...snip
end;
```

The bug here is that it will not call `DoAdjustSize` unless either **sfWidth** or **sfHeight** scaling flags are present.

The fix is to not try to outsmart yourself, and `DoAdjustSize` regardless:

```
procedure TWinControl.AlignControls(AControl: TControl; var Rect: TRect);
begin
   //...snip

   // Apply any constraints
   //QC125995: Don't look to scaling flags to decide if we should adjust size
   if Showing {and ((sfWidth in FScalingFlags) or (sfHeight in FScalingFlags))} then
      DoAdjustSize;

   //...snip
end;
```

### The "Doesn't autosize on resize" bug

The previous fix makes the panel AutoSize when it contains child **TControl** or **TWinControl**. But there is another bug when the panel contains a **TOleControl**. The bug was introduced in Delphi XE. Unlike the above bug, caused by someone thinking they were being clever, this one is much more subtle.

When a **TOleControl** is resized, its **SetBounds** method is called. This is the original, functional, code:

```
procedure TOleControl.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
   if ((AWidth <> Width) and (Width > 0)) or ((AHeight <> Height) and (Height > 0)) then
   begin
      //...snip: perhaps tweak AWidth and AHeight
   end;

   inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);
end;
```

In XE2 timeframe, the code was changed to so that it notifies the underlying **Ole** control that it's bounds are about to change:

```
procedure TOleControl.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
var
   LRect: TRect;
begin
   if ((AWidth <> Width) and (Width > 0)) or ((AHeight <> Height) and (Height > 0)) then
   begin
      //...snip: perhaps tweak AWidth and AHeight

      //Notify the underlying Ole control that its bounds are about to change
      if FOleInplaceObject <> nil then
      begin
         LRect := Rect(Left, Top, Left+AWidth, Top+AHeight);
         FOleInplaceObject.SetObjectRects(LRect, LRect);
      end;
   end;

   inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);
end;
```

Unbeknownst to the author, this exposes a bug in **TWinControl**. The problem with calling [`IOleInPlaceObject.SetObjectRects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is that it the Ole control (e.g. Internet Explorer) turns around and sends the [`WM_WindowPosChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632652(v=vs.85).aspx) message. The **WMWindowPoschanged** handler in **TWinControl** doesn't handle the message correctly.

While the regular `SetBounds` method correctly calls:

```
procedure SetBounds;
begin
   UpdateAnchorRules;
   UpdateExplicitBounds;
   RequestAlign; //the important one we need
end;
```

The `WMWindowPosChanged` method only calls:

```
procedure WMWindowPosChanged;
begin
   UpdateBounds; //which only calls UpdateAnchorRules
end;
```

This means that the WinControl adjusts its size; but its parent is never realigned to handle the new auto size.

### The Fix

The fix is either:

- don't call `IOleInPlaceObject.SetObjectRects` from SetBounds at all. Delphi 5 didn't do it and it worked fine
- change WMWindowPosChanged so that it also calls **RequestAlign**:

  ```
    procedure TWinControl.WMWindowPosChanged;
    begin
       UpdateBounds;
       RequestAlign; //don't forget to autosize our parent since we're changing our size behind our backs (e.g. TOleControl)
    end;
  ```
- change UpdateBounds to also call **RequestAlign**:

  ```
   procedure TWinControl.UpdateBounds;
   begin
      UpdateAnchorRules;
      //UpdateExplicitBounds; SetBounds calls this; why are we not calling it?
      RequestAlign; //in response to WM_WindowPosChanged            
   end;
  ```

I settled on a fourth solution; one that leaves the bug intact, but fixes it enough for me.

The bug is that:

- **WMWindowPosChanged** doesn't handle size changes correctly
- but **SetBounds** does

So lets use **SetBounds** first.

Leverage the (mostly) correct code in **SetBounds** to do all the autosizing. Then we can call `SetObjectRects`. When **WMWindowPosChanged** receives its `WM_WindowPosChanging` message, it will have nothing to do - and therefore not do anything wrong.

## tl;dr

```
procedure TOleControl.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
var
  LRect: TRect;
begin
  if ((AWidth <> Width) and (Width > 0)) or ((AHeight <> Height) and (Height > 0)) then
  begin
     //...snip: perhaps fiddle with AWidth or AHeight

     {Removed. Call *after* inheirted SetBounds
     //Notify the underlying Ole control that its bounds are about to change
     if FOleInplaceObject <> nil then
     begin
        LRect := Rect(Left, Top, Left+AWidth, Top+AHeight);
        FOleInplaceObject.SetObjectRects(LRect, LRect);
     end;}
  end;

  inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);

  //moved to call *after* SetBounds, we need SetBounds to happen first.       
  //TWinControl's WMWindowPosChanged does not handle autosizing correctly
  //while SetBounds does.
  //Notify the underlying Ole control that its bounds are already about to change
  if FOleInplaceObject <> nil then
  begin
     LRect := Rect(Left, Top, Left+AWidth, Top+AHeight);
     FOleInplaceObject.SetObjectRects(LRect, LRect);
  end;
end;
```

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.